# Read Only Text widget in python3-tkinter; cross platform

Tags: python, text, python-3.x, tkinter, readonly

How to suppress end user ability to edit/add/delete text in a Text widget? (Python v3.2.. and tkinter)

The point is to **suppress only the ability to change/add/delete text** but not to castrate other features. Perhaps a NoEdit Text widged would be a better name.

I've tried `.text['state'] = 'disabled'` and it works *almost* OK in Windows (it still allows user to select/copy text highlights the selection, page up/down and up/down buttons work. The only thing broken seems to be the cursor made invisible.)

**But on MacIntosh everything is broken. No highlights, no select/copy,... UGH**

Since Tkinter has practically no documentation in Python, I've searched and found some TCL advise, to derive a new class and suppress the **insert** and **delete** functions.

So, I've tried as so:

```
class roText(tk.Text):
    def insert(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print(" Hey  - Im inside roText.insert")
        pass
    def delete(self,*args,**twargs):
        pass    
    def pInsert(self,*args,**twargs):
        super().insert(*args,**twargs)
```

Unfortunately it didn't work right. Apparently **tkinter does not use those insert and delete functions when end user enters/deletes code.** Perhaps those TCL insert/delete are something else, and I lost something in translation from TCL and Swahili. What functions does `tkinter.Text` use for end user editing text? Hopefully they are not internal...

**So, is there a way to modify the Text widget to suppress only end user editing?**
Is there a way to do it without diving inside and overriding internal Tkinter code, so the stuff doesn't get broken by next releases of Tkinter?

Looking at the Idle shell window, I see that they've managed to suppress edits (except for the last line). So there is a way. But what is it and how costly?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for bumping an old question, but I was searching for an answer to this question also and finally found a solution. The solution I found involves overriding the key bindings when the text widget has focus and is pretty simple. Found [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

To override the bindings of a widget there is a bind function where you pass a string of what is to be overridden and the new function you want it to call.

```
    self.txtBox.bind("<Key>", self.empty)
```

Somewhere else in the class you'll need to define the function to handle the event.

```
    def empty(self, event):
        return "break"
```

By returning the string "break" the event handler knows to stop after your function, instead of continuing with the default action.

I hope this answers your question. Cheers.

Comment: Works well for me; only tested on linux so far.  No need for the separate empty function though.  Just do: `self.txtBox.bind('<Key>', lambda _: 'break')`

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `disabled` state doesn't seem to work on the Mac is because it turns off the binding that gives focus to the widget. Without focus, the highlighting on a Mac doesn't show up. If you set the state to `disabled` but then assign a binding to `<ButtonPress-1>` to explicitly set focus to the disabled text widget, you can then select and copy text and the highlighting will show.

As for the cursor disappearing... arguably, that's what's supposed to happen. The cursor tells the user "this is where text will get inserted". Since no text will get inserted, having that visual clue would be confusing to the user. What you could do instead, if it was really important, is to insert a small image wherever they click to simulate the cursor.

To answer your question about whether the widget actually uses the `insert` and `delete` methods:  the methods on the actual underlying widget are what the default bindings use, so overriding them in a subclass has no effect. You would need to redo all the default bindings for that to work. It's doable, but a lot of work.

Unfortunately, this is one area where programming in Tcl really shines, because you *can* simply disable the `insert` and `delete` commands of the widget. Of course, you can do that directly in Tkinter also since ultimately it runs tcl code to do everything, but that would involve writing some tcl code which is not a very good solution from the perspective of a Python coder.

I think the best solution is to use the disabled state, then add in just enough bindings to do what you want.

Here's a simple example that works by explicitly setting focus on a mouse button click. With this code I'm able to click and swipe to select a region, or double- or triple-click to select words and lines:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = tk.Text(width=40, height=20)
        self.text.bind("<1>", self.set_focus)
        self.text.insert("end", "\n".join(dir(tk.Tk)))
        self.text.configure(state="disabled")
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def set_focus(self, event):
        '''Explicitly set focus, so user can select and copy text'''
        self.text.focus_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: OK, I had a chance to test on Mac, and  the text.focus_set() bound to <1> fixed the problem, just as you said it would.  **Thanks!!!**  (Perhaps this page can be cleaned up for others looking for a solution. And I've seen many on the web).   


    Unfortunately as I was afraid it was apparently one of many problems with Tkinter port to Mac.   'green' color doesn't work on buttons, the text on buttons needs more spacing (this one could be resolution related), etc...    Those are easy to work around, and I just hope worse will not show up

Answer (score -1):

@BryanOakley   It took me a while to test your suggestion since I have no Mac.
Unfortunately Mac implementation of Python is buggy. 
I've added focus, ie my disable function which I call after creating a window and inserting text, now calls first:

```
self.txt['state'] = 'disabled'
```

and then

```
self.txt.focus_set()
```

Which is what I think you've suggested.

It "kind of" worked. Ie: when selecting text (click and drag or double-click) highlighting works *most* of the time.   Python must have some bad memory references or such bugs: Sometimes highlighting doesn't work at first, then it starts working (in the same window) after more clicking. Sometimes when program is invoked it works right of the bat.   Sometimes selecting with Shift-rightArrow key will work but selecting with the mouse will not. Then starts working again. Or it will work fine in one window but not in another one (both of the same class), then starts working in all windows...etc...

The good thing is that adding focus did not affect badly Windows (ie all works fine as without focus.
I guess at this point I will just hope that future/next release of Python for Mac will fix those bugs..

BTW, it seems that Mac is a bit of an orphan for Python.   Implementation is much uglier then for Windows. I mean the fonts look worse, the buttons, etc..  Or it could be due to different screen resolutions and Python ports that poorly account for those. Not sure

Anyway.   Thank you for your help and suggestion to use focus for Mac.

Comment: You need to call `focus_set` in the callback for the `<1>` event, not just when you create the widget. It looks from your answer you're only setting the focus once. I repeat: for the highlight to show, the widget must have focus. If you give it focus, it can lose focus whenever you click anywhere else. Adding a binding to `<1>` to set the focus will make sure it always has focus when you try to do a selection (since any selection always begins with a mouse click).

Comment: @BryanOakley   I don't know what you mean by "callback for the <1> event". It seems my guess was wrong... 
My next guess is that you suggest to bind single click in my text gadget to some callback function which will call ...txt.focus_set()
And perhaps do it also for a double click, and a triple click (if tkinter has <Tripple-1> didn't check yet)>   Right now I have binding/callback only for <Double-1> but of course I could make a special binding and a one line callback with focus_set() just for this.     I'll try and send it to my "Mac client" to test...   Thanks again.

Comment: my original answer said "assign a binding to <ButtonPress-1> to explicitly set focus to the disabled text widget". I thought that was clear enough, but obviously not. I've added an example to clarify. Also, you don't need to do the same for a double- or triple-click, since the only way to do a double- or triple- click is to first do a single-click, so this solution will let you double- or triple-click to select words and lines, as well as click-and drag to select a region.

Comment: @BryanOakley
Thanks for adding the example.  ( I've not known that <1> is alternative to <Button-1> hence some confusion).
Yes, I have tested (with print()) that setting focus on <Button-1> does it also when double clicked.  In fact setting it for <Enter> may suffice, since one needs Enter before clicking.     But I've left all three focus_set for now, since not clear what causes the bug in Mac.    I'll post when I get a chance to test on Mac.
    (And thanks for the "bonus", the use of "dir")

Comment: doing it on `<Enter>` seems like a really bad idea if there are any other widgets in your GUI. You don't want focus changing just because the user bumped the mouse a little. As for what causes the bug, I already answered that in my original answer. It's not so much a bug as it is a side effect of the design.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, Ive learned that Enter is a bad idea quickly after I put it in my real program with multiple windows... :-) So it is now exactly as you've suggested first on <1> only.. [] As to "this" being a bug:   My understanding is that Tkinter is supposed to work the same on all platforms except for the native look and feel and perhaps some platform conventions.     Are you suggesting that highlight and such are supposed to work on PC but not on Mac when text is disabled?   I'm not a Mac user obviously, but it seems weird.  Makes me wander what else will work different on Mac or Linux